# Transparent tcolorbox so I can see my watermark

Tags: tcolorbox, transparency, transparent

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots,tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=5,
    contents={Jason Bowens},
    opacity=.2
}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{calligra}
\newcommand{\I}{\textup{\large\calligra i}\,}


\usepackage{mathtools} %\xhookrightarrow

% \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[margin=1in,top=.71in,bottom=1in,paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in]{geometry}

\makeatletter\let\gb\@gobble\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[R,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line

\fancyfoot[L,LO]{
{\tiny Property of Jason Bowens 
for  Ivan Danilenko \\  Math 141 class at the \\ University of California, Berkeley
} } % other info in "inner" position of footer line

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw, opacityback=.2,colback=white,breakable,enhanced]
Question: How far is a {\tt general immersion} from an {\tt inclusion} of a {\tt submanifold}?

The best case senario.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[thick] (0.2-.1,0.2+.1) arc (135:315:.07cm);
\draw[thick,->] (-1+.2,1)--(1-.2,1);
\draw[thick,->] (-1+.1,1-.1)--(0-.2,0+.2);
\draw[thick,->] (0+.2,0+.2)--(1-.2,1-.2);
\draw[](0,0)node[]{${\I}\gb{ii}(\mathcal{M}\gb{ii})$\footnote{{\tt submanifold} in $\mathcal{N}$}};
\draw[](-1,1)node[]{$\mathcal{M}$};
\draw[](1,1)node[]{$\mathcal{N}$};
\draw[](0,1+.1)node[]{${\I}$};
\draw[](0,1-.1)node[]{\tt immersion};
\draw[thick](-.6-.1,.6-.1)node[rotate=-45]{\tt dffmrphsm};
\draw[](.6+.1,.6-.1)node[rotate=45]{\tt inclusion};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
But we dont know what {\tt dffmrphsm} is?

This is not always the case.

\underline{Reason}: ${\I}$ may fail to be {\tt injecttive}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{-3}\def\b{0.0}
    \draw[] (\a,\b) circle (1cm);
\draw[blue] (\a-1,\b) node[]{$\bullet$};
\draw[] (\a+1,\b) node[red]{$\bullet$};
    \draw[thick,->] (\a+1+.2,\b)--(\a+2-.2,\b);
\def\SIN{{cos((\x)r)/(1+(sin((\x)r))^2)},{sin((\x)r)*cos((\x)r)/(1+(sin((\x)r))^2)}}
\draw[domain={0}:{2*pi},samples=500] plot(\SIN);
\draw[Purple2] (0,0) node[]{$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
What the {\bf\color{red}} sees,
\\
\begin{center}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[very thick, ->](-1+.2,0)--(-.3,0);
    \def\k{-1.0}
    \def\seg{{\k*sqrt(1-(\x)^2)},\x}
    \draw[domain=-.25:.25] plot(\seg);
    \draw[] (\k,0) node[blue]{$\bullet$};
\def\SIN{{cos((\x)r)/(1+(sin((\x)r))^2)},{sin((\x)r)*cos((\x)r)/(1+(sin((\x)r))^2)}}
\draw[domain={.35*pi}:{.65*pi},samples=500] plot(\SIN);
\draw[blue] (0,0) node[]{$\bullet$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw[very thick, ->](-1+.2,0)--(-.3,0);
    \def\k{1.0}
    \def\seg{{\k*sqrt(1-(\x)^2)-2},\x}
    \draw[domain={-.25}:{.25}] plot(\seg);
    \draw[] (\k-2,0) node[red]{$\bullet$};
\def\SIN{{cos((\x)r)/(1+(sin((\x)r))^2)},{sin((\x)r)*cos((\x)r)/(1+(sin((\x)r))^2)}}
\draw[domain={1.35*pi}:{1.65*pi},samples=500] plot(\SIN);
\draw[red] (0,0) node[]{$\bullet$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
The {\tt image} is not a {\tt manifold}.
\\ \\
In contrast to {\tt local diffeomorphism}, requiring an {\tt immersion} to be {\tt bijective} doesn't solf the issue.
\\ \\
\underline{Reason 2}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[](-3,0)node[]{(}--(-2,0)node[]{)};
\draw[->,very thick] (-1.8,0)--(-1.2,0);
\def\a{0.0}\def\b{1.5*pi}\def\d{.1}
\draw[blue,domain=\a:\b,samples=500] plot({cos((\x)r)},{sin((\x)r)});
\draw[blue] ({cos((\b)r)},{sin((\b)r)})--(2,{sin((\b)r)});
\draw[blue] ({cos((\a)r)},{sin((\a)r)})--({cos((\a)r)},{sin((\b)r)+\d});
\draw[dashed] ({cos((\a)r)},{sin((\b)r)+\d/2}) circle (.15cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0.6,-1)node[rotate=90]{(}--(0.6,1)node[rotate=90]{)};
    \draw[blue,domain=0.7:2.2,samples=500] plot(\x,{sin(40*(1/\x)r)})node[right]{$\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$};
    \draw[](-4,0)node[]{(}--(-3,0)node[]{)};
    \draw[](-2,0)node[]{(}--(-1,0)node[]{)};
    \draw[] (-3.5,0+.3) node[](1){};
    \draw[] (-1.5,0-.3) node[](2){};
    \draw[] (0.6-.1,0-.1)    node[](3){};
    \draw[] (1.5,-1-.2) node[](4){};
    \draw[->] (1) [out=50,in=120] to (3);
    \draw[->] (2) [out=-50,in=-120] to (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I can't see my watermark through the box.

And also, what if I want to have color in my background  `colback=red!20!` and I want to see through it?

I tried `enhanced jigsaw, opacityback=.2,`...didn't work

Comment: Upvoted, let's see if somebody can help. But --- `opacityback=200?` seems a no-no, and this example is not "minimal" at all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at "Drawing Scheme" section in `tcolorbox` documentation, you will see that the `frame` around a `tcolorbox` is not a frame but a filled rectangle which is later on covered by the `interior` part. Therefore, if you want to build a transparent framed `tcolorbox`, you need to change the default `frame` and `interior` constructions. This is what is done in following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=5,
    contents={Jason Bowens},
    opacity=1
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
enhanced, 
% The default filled rectangle is just a frame now
frame code={\draw[rounded corners, blue, thick](frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);}, 
% No ìnterior` is drawn
interior empty, 
]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case that a background color is desired, it's possible to use `opacityback` option.

You can also forget the `frame code` solution, and use the `opacityframe` option. But in this case remember that both colors will mix on the background of your text, as it's shown in following second box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=5,
    contents={Jason Bowens},
    opacity=1
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
enhanced, 
% The default filled rectangle is just a frame now
frame code={\draw[rounded corners, blue, line width=.5mm]([shift={(.25mm,-.25mm)}]frame.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-.25mm,.25mm)}]frame.south east);}, 
colback=red!30, opacityback=.5 
]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
colframe=blue, opacityframe=.5,
colback=red!30, opacityback=.5 
]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !! What if I want to have color in my background  ```colback=red!20!``` and I want to see through it?

Comment: @TheGreatJRB I've updated the answer. If you add a background color, you have to correct `frame code` to avoid a white line between frame and inner color.

Comment: is it possible to make both cases breakable?

Comment: You will probably have to adapt  the code, but yes, it's possible